# typing tm character

Tags: edit-mode

I need the TM character. Looking through the documentation it is confusing the way the instructions are worded. It says to type T, then alt-backspace, then M, if I understand it correctly. But nothing works.
Any ideas what I am missing?
I'm using 2.91.0
[enter link description here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/texts/editing.html#accent-characters)

Comment: First of all, you need to make sure that your font supports that character (the default BFont does not seem to)
Then maybe a workaround: Open your favorite Word Processor app, type (TM), let it autocorrect to ™ and then copy and paste into blender.

Comment: Sounds good. This sort of info should be in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

For many special characters that can't normally be typed on your keyboard, it is much easier to just copy/ paste from some word processing app like Libre Writer and paste to blender.

In Windows, the [™ character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark_symbol) is entered with <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0153</kbd>

You can simply copy paste from Libre (or some other app) into Blender text object, change the font to something other than bfont and it should work.

[image]

Comment: Non-hyperlinked, easily copy-and-pasteable version: `™™™™™`